# Black Screen CentOS 7, VirtualBox-5.1.10

Tags: centos, virtualbox, screen-lock

I have CentOS 7 installed like Guest on VirtualBox (Mac OS Sierra like Anfitrion)...

My Problem is, when I'm using CentOS and change to MAC, Appears black Screen with a Cursor and Mouse Pointer, but I cant't to obtain Control over CentOS... Then I need to restar and lost my unsaved documents.

Here my Screen...
[image]

How solve this?